# Using LINQ2SQL Efficiently

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am a HUGE LINQ2SQL Fan. But I use a lot of DataContext in my each function and subsequent use the queries. However, I know there is a better way to do it...

Something like this, maybe?

```
 protected dbMYDataContext FA(dbMYDataContext dt)
    {
         using (dt = new dbMYDataContext())
        {
            return dt;
        }

    }

 protected void FunctionA() : FA
        {

        }
 protected void FunctionB() : FA
        {

        }
```

So the mantra is that, whenever you want to create a DataContext, inherit or call this function FA. But, I am getting error when I am inheriting it. What seems to be the problem and what is the best practices to reduce the use of DataContext all the time.

Advices?

Comment: Is your posting correct? It looks like you're trying to implement inheritance at the function level rather than at the class level which doesn't make any sense. What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh! I got it. My mistake...Yeah. Thats been solved. So should I create a class and then try to inherit that class?

Comment: Only create the DataContext when you need it. You will use unneccesary resources otherwise and risk not getting correct data due to Object Tracking in L2S

Comment: @SB: So every time I want to do a Select, I am using DataContext. Is this okay to do?

Comment: Yes that's right but try and keep it to only 1 per function as per my code example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I do when using L2S that vasty improve things alot.

1) Use the **using** statement as you have shown in your question. This is the correct way of doing things

2) If I am doing a read only query... I set (DataContext).ObjectTrackingEnabled = false. This basically does not track the objects and improves performance a bit. It is set to true by default.

3) If I use a query more than 5 times in a program, I pre-compile the query to make things happen quicker than they would. There are a few caveats with this approach, but using .ToList() at the end seems to fix them all for me :D Follow up link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/compiled-or-bust.html

It is worth remembering that every time you create a data context, you are getting the latest data. Example, you create a class instance of a data context, another user updates a table, you will not see it (or at least I never do, but it could be the way im doing things. So be warned). :)

Example Code *(Not Tested)*:

```
protected void MyFunction()
{
    using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
    {
         // uncomment the following line for read only queries
         // db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
         // implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmmmm, thanks SB! So suppose I am selecting or fetching items for read only, then I would use: (DataContext).ObjectTrackingEnabled

Comment: Yes that is correct. Bare in mind that you can only use what you return in your results. Eg. You pull back the customers table only, you will not be able to get their orders without requerying. Make sense? If not I will do a code example for you tomorrow :)

Comment: @SBlacker: If you do need your orders you need to use DataLoadOptions to immediately load them. You can still do 'using' and no need to requery

Comment: @Pleun: Or you can pull them back in the select ;)  select p.customers, p.orders

Answer (score 1):

Use Unit of Work pattern

[Refer this article.](http://www.robertgray.net.au/2011/1/29/linq-to-sql-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx)